# IP whitelist checking using loops, C#

Tags: c#, loops, ip, ip-address, whitelist

So today I was messing around with some IP protection for a program I am making.

The whitelist for IPs is hosted on pastebin.

My program downloads the IPs, splits it into an array of strings.

My program also checks the ip using https://wtfismyip.com/text

What I want to do is compare each string from the array and check if it is the current IP.

If the IP is not the current IP by the end, then it will close.

How would I do this?

Example of the code:

```
    for (int i = 0; i < iplist.Length; i++)
    {
        if(iplist[i] == WebIP)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Passed");
        }
        else
        {
            this.Close();
        }
    }
```

Comment: You need a boolean variable set to false before entering the loop. When you find your IP set that variable to true and break out the for loop. At this point you will know if you have found the IP

Comment: How long is this whitelist?

Comment: @EdPlunkett not long, maybe 10 IPs long

Answer (score 2):

assuming you're going to test lots of times, create a `HashSet<T>` of the whitelist (or similarly: blacklist); assuming it is a `string`:

```
var whiteList = new HashSet<string>(iplist);
```

(do this once, not every time you need to check)

then just check `.Contains`:

```
bool isOK = whiteList.Contains(WebIP);
```

job done, and very efficiently

Comment: This is a really good idea, due to `Contains` becoming O(1) operation, but what about the `Hashset<T>` declaration? Wouldn't that by itself be O(n) operation? Which should still result in the same performance as if you used simply `.Any(Predicate<T>)`. Potentially even worse.

Comment: If the element is at index 0 it would be way worse to recreate the whole collection.

Comment: @Deadzone it is usually the case that you use the same whitelist to process many many requests, in which case the O(N) initial cost is both accurate and irrelevant :) the mention of `WebIP` suggests this is a web server, making this even more likely to handle more than one request

Comment: That's true, but if OP is working with the collection only here I'd go with `.Any()` instead. But if it's the case you described than yes, that would be much more efficient solution.

Comment: @Deadzone even if we assume the best case of no invalid IPs ever, assuming uniform distribution means you're still paying O(N/2) which is ultimately just: O(N). It all depends on how big N is, though :)

Comment: Of course that's true, that's what Big O notation is about you should always assume N is a really big number, but I'd still prefer waiting just 365 days rather than 365 * 2 days and there is also the chance that the operation would be O(1) which wouldn't be able to happen if you have a consistent O(n) operation. `Any<T>(Predicate<T>)` accepts a predicate which makes it more flexible + the fact that it would give a more reasonable time depending on the collection size itself makes it even more flexible. You wont get any of that when using `Contains<T>(T)` + `Hashset<T>` declaration.

Comment: @Deadzone I think you're getting a bit carried away here; if we want to represent whether something *contains* a flat value (directly, not a sub-member), then *semantically* that is what `.Contains()` conveys... and is what a hash-set optimizes for

Comment: My point was that the `Hashset<T>` declaration would never be any less than O(n) where `Any<T>(Predicate<T>)`'s time complexity can vary which will never yield slower result than the former, only possibly faster. I'm sorry if I extend this too much, but it's just a fun topic for me to discuss :)

Comment: If the addresses are always either IPv4 or IPv6, it would be even more efficient to work with their binary representation (4 or 16 bytes), instead of strings.  At the very least, you'd spend less memory holding the whitelist.  But it's only easy if you hard-code one or the other, while strings are flexible to either IPv4 or IPv6.

Answer (score 1):

You can use some *LINQ* to make the code more readable:

```
if (iplist.Any(ip => ip == WebIP))
{
    MessageBox.Show("Passed");
}
else
{
    this.Close();
}
```

Comment: or just... `.Contains(WebIP)` ?

Comment: @MarcGravell That would also do the job but it seems more imperative like this, at least to me..

Comment: I'd be cautious, though; LINQ has multiple special-case optimizations for things that it can do efficiently - ICollection for `.Count()` etc; it isn't the case *today*, but I wouldn't rule out `Contains<T>(T val)` checking for `ISet<T>`, which would mean that it is automatically optimized for a range of common scenarios, where-as `Any(x => x == y)` *won't be able to use that*, *and* involves a delegate creation with context capture object

Answer (score 0):

You can have a flag and set it accordingly like

```
 bool flag = false;
    for (int i = 0; i < iplist.Length; i++)
    {
    if(iplist[i] == WebIP)
     {
       flag = true;
       break;
     }
   }

if(flag)
  MessageBox.Show("Passed");
else
  this.Close();
```